# Android in-app-update not workin on some phones

Tags: android

I implemented in app update from google services

```
protected void checkUpdate() {
    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnFailureListener(err -> onUpdateError());
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, this, UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                onUpdateError();
            }
        } else {
            onNoUpdate();
        }
    });
}

...  implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0'
```

It works just fine on most of the phones. But i had some where it does not trigger any callback (addOnFailureListener,addOnSuccessListener or addOnCompleteListener)

First 2 lines are executed then it jump over callbacks

One of the phone :

- play store 27.1.14-21
- android 9

Thx